# Maintaining Online User Count Socket.io NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'm trying to keep track of all the users logged in to my `socket.io` / `nodejs` app.

When someone logs in I simply do:

```
sessionobj[result[0].username] = sessionId;
```

This also works fine if someone opens the site in multiple tabs, as they will still have the same username, and will only be added once to the `sessionobj`.

The problem occurs when someone closes one of the tabs. Ideally, I want the user to be "logged out" when he has no tabs open, however, I'm not sure how to accomplish this. For example, if the users has 2 tabs open and I add the line:

```
delete sessionobj[socket.handshake.session.username];
```

to the `socket.on('disconnect'` event, the user will be deleted when he closes one of the tabs, even if the other tab still remains open. Is there any way to keep track of this accurately?

Answer (score 0):

Just store information about the current number of tabs somewhere, e.g. in the localstorage. Whenever a tab is opened you add one and when a tab is closed you substract one from said number.
Thus you know how many windows are open and can simply not call your disconnect event when there are more tabs of your app around.